# KafkaStreams Left Join DSL: inserting on outer null value

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have a mix-and-match DSL-PAPI topology. The DSL part joins pageviews("pageviews" topic) with users ("users" topic) of those pageviews. I want to join both, so in case the user is new, then create a new "user" from pvs information into the "users" topic, and do nothing otherwise.

So I'm trying to do a left join between pageviews and users, and in case the user comes null, that means no user was created yet with this key, so in that case I create one.

In code, I get pageviews as stream and user as table, joined them producing new User when user comes null in the join, and then filtering and sending to "users" those new users.

```
    val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
    val pageviewsTopic: KStream[Key, Pageview] = builder.stream("pageviews")
      .map((muipk, pageview) => (new MerchantUserPartitionKey(muipk.merchantSiteId, muipk.uid) -> pageview))

    val usersTopic: KTable[MerchantUserPartitionKey, user] = builder.table("users")

    val joinedPageviewsWithUsers: KStream[MerchantUserPartitionKey, User] =
      pageviewsTopic.leftJoin(
        usersTopic,
        new ValueJoiner[Pageview, User, User] {
          override def apply(pageview: Pageview, user: User): User = {
            logger.info("JOIN PAGEVIEW-user")
            if (user == null) {
              new User(UUIDUtils.generateRandomId(), pageview.uid /*, some other data */)
            } else {
              logger.info("user already created.")
              null
            }
          }
        })
    // Generate users.
    joinedPageviewsWithUsers.
      filter((key, user) => user != null ).
      to("users")
```

DSL topology generated looks like this:

```
  Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [pageviews])
      --> KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005
      <-- KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000005 (topic: KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001-repartition)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000006
  Sub-topology: 1
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000007 (topics: [KSTREAM-MAP-0000000001-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000008
    Processor: KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000008 (stores: [users-STATE-STORE-0000000002])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000009
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000007
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000009 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000010
      <-- KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000008
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000003 (topics: [users])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000004
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000010 (topic: users)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000009
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000004 (stores: [user-STATE-STORE-0000000002])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000003
```

However, when running this for several pageviews with same key, the "users" create new users, but it always joins with "null". So, it looks like the store is not updated with the newly generated data in "users" topic, even if it shows using the `user-STATE-STORE-0000000002`.

Do you need to do something extra to get data into the store? Is this somehow a KafkaStreams anti-pattern (write to the topic you're previously joining with)?

**UPDATE** with more info:

- Keys are not null
- ValueJoiner code is executed (printouts are shown), only that user value comes always null.
- Users are written to "users" topic (in this case, by logic it does it every time it enters the ValueJoiner, since it always finds the outer value to be null and so it inserts the user into "users")

Comment: Do you have any `null` keys? Did you verify that `apply` is called? Did you verify if data is written into topic "users" ?

Comment: Answered in an update to clarify (basically "no", "yes", "yes")

Comment: Can you check the lag for topics "users" -- did the KTable catch up? Can you use Interactive Queries to check if the table was updated?

Comment: Sorry, rebuilt the cluster already and re-worked with PAPI. However by your answer I understand this was supported, is it? Lag on users topic: how does the consumption for this topic to feed StateStore appear when checking for the application consumer-group? Also, I was not using IQ here. What was your hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, this should work as expected. Not sure atm what might have been the problem. If you read a topic as a KTable, you can monitor the lag as for any other topic (application.id == group.id).

Comment: I think the problem is time: it does not give the time for the store to read from the topic to make the join. This may take some time, and for tests I would like to be immediate. How could I minimize the round-trip time from producing into a topic via a sink via PAPI forward, to the time it is available in the store build via `table(topic)` in DSL, and is read via `store.get` again in the Processor?

Comment: I see. That makes sense. For testing, you might want to check out the `TopologyTestDriver`: https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html

Comment: I am using the [Scala EmbeddedKafka](https://github.com/manub/scalatest-embedded-kafka) library. I tried several settings (retention, poll times, etc) to no avail. Introducing delays between publishing allows time for the KTable to update (seems like 5s delay works well). But that creates some unpredictability on the consumers, I guess bc they use the same consumer group so when you go to read, it may be that offsets have been moved and you got nothing to read. TopologyTestDriver with PAPI was published not much ago, maybe it's time to upgrade and check it out. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I solved it with a mix of delays between `publishToKafka` calls, plus using explicit `Partitioner` (for `forward` in PAPI) and `StreamPartitioner` (DSL) with same logic (even if they use the same key, with no fields added!). This basically does a HashPartitioner-like on the fields of the key, but something may differ in default implementations because default partitioners (DSL vs PAPI) did not send the data from same key to the same partition as I expected.

Comment: @xmar, I am having the same issue. I am doing a left join of KStream with GlobalKTable. If I insert 2 records which are having same key and different value then the join is happening fine, but if I send both records with < 100 ms gap between them, then GlobalKTable is not able to consider the state change after first record. I understand that you introduced some delay, but that delay won't increase your consumer lag in case if your app is write intensive?

Comment: If your `GlobalKTable` is fed from a topic that is written to by other parts of the topology, there are different subtopologies. Then there is no way for `KafkaStreams` to know they are directly connected: should wait/lookup on it, etc. And then, it is subject to your production/consumption settings. I wrote answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a stream is in a subtopology that looks up into a table that is in another subtopology, then there may be regular consumption/production delays involved. This happens for example when you define streams or tables from topics directly. If you can use more meaningful directives like `through` (which writes to topic but lets topology know it's going to still be used in this topology) it will help `KafkaStreams` to know how there is such relation.